# Strange SARMAX fit with python statsmodels

Tags: python, statsmodels

I've a dataset with 48 obs (monthly) and python have been able to fit the SARIMAX ((4, 1, 3), (3, 0, **5**)) model... which to me seems quite odd. How does it calculates the B^(12*5) term and the subsequent ones since I have just 48 data points?
I've also tried with ((0, 1, 4), (**5**, 0, 1)) and it works... Also, I've computed the MAPE agaist the next 12 periods and it's quite good (3% and 6%).

Thoughts?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, estimation is done using the assumption that pre-sample observations are drawn from the unconditional distribution of the implied SARIMA process.

SARIMAX models are estimated using a state space approach, and if you are a frequentist the this process is referred to as the "initialization" of the first state vector, while if you are a Bayesian then you would think of this as putting a particular prior on the first state vector (the state vector contains all the required lags of the process, so the "initialization", or prior, describes enough pre-sample observations to allow the model to be fit).

While this is a perfectly reasonable approach to setting up the model so that it can be estimated, it doesn't necessarily mean that it is a good idea to specify a model with so many parameters and so few observations. Your estimates will begin to depend more on the prior rather than on the data.